# animate the div from top to bottom using angularjs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html

I use angularjs..the code works well the red div with text is shown at the bottom and when i click on div it animate from bottom to top...but i want to put the div at top and when i click on it...the div slides from top to bottom...i try evrything but nothing help me...please help me

this is my html

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <div>
    <div class="animate-slide" ng-show="slide" ng-click="slide=!slide">
      <center>AngularJS ng-animate<center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

this my css

```
body{
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#slide{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  top:90%;
  background: red;
}  

.animate-slide {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0,);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-slide.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-up;
  animation:0.5s slide-up;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-down;
  animation:0.5s slide-down;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide {
  top:80%;
  display:block!important;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-up
{
  0%   {top:80%;}
  100%  {top:0;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slide-up
{
  0%   {top:80%;}
  100%  {top:0;}
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-down
{
  0%  {top:0;}
  100%   {top:80%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slide-down
{
  0%  {top:0;}
  100%   {top:80%;}
}
```

Comment: Can you create a `fiddle` or `plunkr`?

Comment: This is the link [codepen](http://codepen.io/agramian/pen/JCloz) @AlbertoI.N.J.

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you want to achieve?

Comment: you see the link..??..which i mention in the comment above.??..

Comment: Yes, I saw the link but I don't quite understand the main goal.

Comment: the div which is present at the bottom of the page..i want this div to appear at top and when i click on it ..the div slide from top to bottom...

Comment: So, you want to reverse the process. The red div initially at the top and when you click it, it will slide to the bottom. Is that right?

Comment: EXACTLY i want to reverse the process

Comment: Ok. I figured out how to achieve what you want. I will post my answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, try this code.

You need to remove `ng-show="slide"` and use `ng-class`.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <div>
    <div class="animate-slide" 
         ng-class="{'slide-up': !slide, 'slide-down': slide}" 
         ng-click="slide = !slide">
      <center>AngularJS ng-animate</center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then remove unnecessary `styles`.

**Remove:**

```
.animate-slide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-slide.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-up;
  animation:0.5s slide-up;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-down;
  animation:0.5s slide-down;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide {
  top:80%;
  display:block!important;
}
```

**Then add:**

```
.animate-slide.slide-down {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-down normal forwards;
  animation:0.5s slide-down normal forwards;
}

.animate-slide.slide-up {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-up normal forwards;
  animation:0.5s slide-up normal forwards;
}
```

**Your code will be like this:**

```
body{
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#slide{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  top:90%;
  background: red;
}  

.animate-slide {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0,);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.animate-slide.slide-down {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-down normal forwards;
  animation:0.5s slide-down normal forwards;
}

.animate-slide.slide-up {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s slide-up normal forwards;
  animation:0.5s slide-up normal forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-up
{
  0%   {top:80%;}
  100%  {top:0;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slide-up
{
  0%   {top:80%;}
  100%  {top:0;}
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-down
{
  0%  {top:0;}
  100%   {top:80%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slide-down
{
  0%  {top:0;}
  100%   {top:80%;}
}
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/aj0foj9u/1/).**

Hope it helps.